# Is the Exchange Traded Fund XQQ (iShares NASDAQ 100) only traded in Canadian dollars?

Tags: etf, foreign-exchange, usd-us-dollar, nasdaq, cad-canadian-dollar

I am looking to invest in Canadian dollars via my Canadian bank, and I found the ETF [XQQ](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA888CA888&sxsrf=ALeKk02pcVy0bbW9YS6_QqQ5mItQhp3qMA%3A1603563412951&ei=lG-UX4XHOZy90PEPhK-T4Ag&q=xqq%20stock%20price&oq=xqq%20stock%20price&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIKCAAQyQMQRhD6ATICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgQIABBHOgoIABDJAxAUEIcCOgQIABBDOgcIABAUEIcCOggIABAWEAoQHlDZDljgFmD_F2gAcAJ4AIABY4gB_wOSAQE2mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiF4emc683sAhWcHjQIHYTXBIwQ4dUDCA0&uact=5). If it says 91.87 CAD, does that mean it is traded in Canadian dollars at $91.87 CAD per share? I'm curious because I want to buy the NASDAQ which I know is US-based, but I'm looking into buying a NASDAQ indexed ETF with Canadian dollars. Is it in Canadian dollars or do I still need to exchange my currency to USD before being able to purchase this ETF?